# Vue.js Vuetify.js - Unknown custom element: <v-list-item>, <v-list-item-title> did you register the component correctly?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I copied code from [Vuetify Data Iterator Filter part](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/data-iterators#filter)

I can use other Vuetify components like `v-btn`, `v-card`, `v-data-table`, `v-data-iterator`, etc.

Only `<v-list-item>` and `<v-list-item-title>` throw errors.

I have no idea what is going on.

Error messages:

> [Vue warn]: Unknown custom element: `<v-list-item>` - did you register
>   the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to
>   provide the "name" option
>
> [Vue warn]: Unknown custom element: `<v-list-item-title>` - did you
>   register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure
>   to provide the "name" option.

HTML:

```
<template>
  <div class="container">
    <v-container fluid grid-list-md style="padding: 0">
      <v-data-iterator
        :items="items"
        :items-per-page.sync="itemsPerPage"
        :page="page"
        :search="search"
        :sort-by="sortBy.toLowerCase()"
        :sort-desc="sortDesc"
        hide-default-footer
      >
        <template v-slot:header>
          <v-toolbar dark color="blue darken-3" class="mb-1">
            <v-text-field
              v-model="search"
              clearable
              flat
              solo-inverted
              hide-details
              prepend-inner-icon="search"
              label="Search"
            ></v-text-field>
            <template v-if="$vuetify.breakpoint.mdAndUp">
              <v-spacer></v-spacer>
              <v-select
                v-model="sortBy"
                flat
                solo-inverted
                hide-details
                :items="keys"
                prepend-inner-icon="search"
                label="Sort by"
              ></v-select>
              <v-spacer></v-spacer>
              <v-btn-toggle v-model="sortDesc" mandatory>
                <v-btn large depressed color="blue" :value="false">
                  <v-icon>arrow_upward</v-icon>
                </v-btn>
                <v-btn large depressed color="blue" :value="true">
                  <v-icon>arrow_downward</v-icon>
                </v-btn>
              </v-btn-toggle>
            </template>
          </v-toolbar>
        </template>

        <template v-slot:default="props">
          <v-layout wrap>
            <v-flex v-for="item in props.items" :key="item.name" xs12 sm6 md4 lg3>
              <v-card>
                <v-card-title class="subheading font-weight-bold">{{ item.name }}</v-card-title>

                <v-divider></v-divider>

                <v-list dense>
                  <v-list-item
                    v-for="(key, index) in filteredKeys"
                    :key="index"
                    :color="sortBy === key ? `blue lighten-4` : `white`"
                  >
                    <v-list-item-content>{{ key }}:</v-list-item-content>
                    <v-list-item-content class="align-end">{{ item[key.toLowerCase()] }}</v-list-item-content>
                  </v-list-item>
                </v-list>
              </v-card>
            </v-flex>
          </v-layout>
        </template>

        <template v-slot:footer>
          <v-layout mt-2 wrap align-center justify-center>
            <span class="grey--text">Items per page</span>
            <v-menu offset-y>
              <template v-slot:activator="{ on }">
                <v-btn dark text color="primary" class="ml-2" v-on="on">
                  {{ itemsPerPage }}
                  <v-icon>keyboard_arrow_down</v-icon>
                </v-btn>
              </template>
              <v-list>
                <v-list-item
                  v-for="(number, index) in itemsPerPageArray"
                  :key="index"
                  @click="updateItemsPerPage(number)"
                >
                  <v-list-item-title>{{ number }}</v-list-item-title>
                </v-list-item>
              </v-list>
            </v-menu>

            <v-spacer></v-spacer>

            <span class="mr-4 grey--text">Page {{ page }} of {{ numberOfPages }}</span>
            <v-btn fab dark color="blue darken-3" class="mr-1" @click="formerPage">
              <v-icon>keyboard_arrow_left</v-icon>
            </v-btn>
            <v-btn fab dark color="blue darken-3" class="ml-1" @click="nextPage">
              <v-icon>keyboard_arrow_right</v-icon>
            </v-btn>
          </v-layout>
        </template>
      </v-data-iterator>
    </v-container>
  </div>
</template>
```

JS:

```
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      itemsPerPageArray: [4, 8, 12],
      search: "",
      filter: {},
      sortDesc: false,
      page: 1,
      itemsPerPage: 4,
      sortBy: "name",
      keys: [
        "Name",
        "Calories",
        "Fat",
        "Carbs",
        "Protein",
        "Sodium",
        "Calcium",
        "Iron"
      ],
      items: [
        {
          name: "Frozen Yogurt",
          calories: 159,
          fat: 6.0,
          carbs: 24,
          protein: 4.0,
          sodium: 87,
          calcium: "14%",
          iron: "1%"
        },
        {
          name: "Ice cream sandwich",
          calories: 237,
          fat: 9.0,
          carbs: 37,
          protein: 4.3,
          sodium: 129,
          calcium: "8%",
          iron: "1%"
        },
        {
          name: "Eclair",
          calories: 262,
          fat: 16.0,
          carbs: 23,
          protein: 6.0,
          sodium: 337,
          calcium: "6%",
          iron: "7%"
        },
        {
          name: "Cupcake",
          calories: 305,
          fat: 3.7,
          carbs: 67,
          protein: 4.3,
          sodium: 413,
          calcium: "3%",
          iron: "8%"
        },
        {
          name: "Gingerbread",
          calories: 356,
          fat: 16.0,
          carbs: 49,
          protein: 3.9,
          sodium: 327,
          calcium: "7%",
          iron: "16%"
        },
        {
          name: "Jelly bean",
          calories: 375,
          fat: 0.0,
          carbs: 94,
          protein: 0.0,
          sodium: 50,
          calcium: "0%",
          iron: "0%"
        },
        {
          name: "Lollipop",
          calories: 392,
          fat: 0.2,
          carbs: 98,
          protein: 0,
          sodium: 38,
          calcium: "0%",
          iron: "2%"
        },
        {
          name: "Honeycomb",
          calories: 408,
          fat: 3.2,
          carbs: 87,
          protein: 6.5,
          sodium: 562,
          calcium: "0%",
          iron: "45%"
        },
        {
          name: "Donut",
          calories: 452,
          fat: 25.0,
          carbs: 51,
          protein: 4.9,
          sodium: 326,
          calcium: "2%",
          iron: "22%"
        },
        {
          name: "KitKat",
          calories: 518,
          fat: 26.0,
          carbs: 65,
          protein: 7,
          sodium: 54,
          calcium: "12%",
          iron: "6%"
        }
      ]
      // value: true
    };
  },
  computed: {
    numberOfPages() {
      return Math.ceil(this.items.length / this.itemsPerPage);
    },
    filteredKeys() {
      return this.keys.filter(key => key !== `Name`);
    }
  },
  methods: {
    nextPage() {
      if (this.page + 1 <= this.numberOfPages) this.page += 1;
    },
    formerPage() {
      if (this.page - 1 >= 1) this.page -= 1;
    },
    updateItemsPerPage(number) {
      this.itemsPerPage = number;
    }
  },
};
```

Output screenshot:

As you can see, other components are working well...

[image]

---

I read the [Vuetify Quick Start](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/getting-started/quick-start) again and make sure I install Vuetify correctly.

Below is `src\plugins\vuetify.js` file

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuetify from 'vuetify/lib'
import 'vuetify/src/stylus/app.styl'

Vue.use(Vuetify, {
  iconfont: 'md',
})
```

and `src\main.js`

```
import Vue from "vue";
import firebase from './components/firebaseInit';
import App from "./App.vue";
import router from "./router";
import vuetify from './plugins/vuetify' // path to vuetify export

Vue.config.productionTip = false;

let app = '';

// initialize the Vue app only when we are sure Firebase is initialized
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(() => {
  if (!app) {
    app = new Vue({
      vuetify,
      router,
      render: h => h(App)
    }).$mount("#app");    

  }
});
```

---

I tried to import the components manually but still, the same errors occurred:

```
import { VListItem, VListItemTitle } from "vuetify/lib";

export default {
  components: {
    'v-list-item': VListItem,
    'v-list-item-title': VListItemTitle
  },
...
}
```

---

I also tried:

1. Remove `.node_modules` folder
2. Run `npm update`
3. Run `npm install`

Still the same errors. I also searched a lot of related posts but no luck.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Turned out I was using `"vuetify": "^1.5.16"` while `VListItem` is introduce in version 2.0

Update Vuetify to latest and [install webpack](https://next.vuetifyjs.com/en/getting-started/quick-start#webpack-installation)  solve the problem.